# Azure Static Web Apps - Visual Studio 2022

Tags: azure, blazor-webassembly, publish

I am trying to publish a Blazor Web Assembly Stand Alone application to Azure Static Web Apps.
My problem is with publishing in Visual Studio 2022, when I click it, it tells me I need to install SWA CLI.

I was following a video from the Azure Team on Publishing, I got to the end but they never had this error.
I read the link visual studio sends you to, it says you need node.js and need to run a command in the terminal.

I installed Node.js and Azure Development from Get Tools and Features in Visual Studio.
I tried the command in the terminal npm install -D @azure/static-web-apps-cli but npm is not recognised.

I tried the same thing on my other laptop and got the same result.

Comment: What is the version of your blazor app? Please share the doc which you are following?

Comment: I was watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vdt-JmG9Ij4&t=827s from  Microsoft Azure Developers I am using the latest version of .NET and Blazor. VS links me to this site https://azure.github.io/static-web-apps-cli/docs/use/install/

Comment: I followed this MSDOC to create Blazor                                                                     
     [app](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/build-and-deploy-net-8-blazor-wasm-apps-with-serverless-apis/ba-p/3988412) and configure swa cli

Answer (score 0):

I followed this  [MSDOC](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/build-and-deploy-net-8-blazor-wasm-apps-with-serverless-apis/ba-p/3988412)  to create a Blazor app and configure the SWA CLI.

- Create a Blazor app:

[image]

- In your Blazor project, add a new file named `staticwebapp.config.json` to the respective [path](https://i.imgur.com/98u42oV.png).

```js
{
    "navigationFallback": {
        "rewrite": "/index.html"
    }
}
```

- Install the  `wasm-tools`  workload for .NET with the command:

`dotnet workload install wasm-tools`.

- Install the Azure Static Web Apps CLI in the respective path.

```
npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli
```

[image]

**To initialize Azure Static Web Apps:**

- Use the `swa init` command to initialize the Azure Static Web Apps configuration for a project. This command creates an `swa-cli.config.json` file, which holds the configuration settings for an Azure Static Web Apps project.

[image]

- Change `"appDevserverUrl": "http://localhost:yourLocalport"` in `swa-cli.config.json` file.

> - Use `swa start` to run your app locally.
>
> > [image]
> > [image]
> > [image]
>
> - Use `swa build` to build your app.
> - Use `swa deploy`  to deploy your app to [Azure](https://azure.github.io/static-web-apps-cli/docs/use/install/).
>   [image]

**swa deploy:**

[image]
**Azure:**

[image]